# How to show loader if a has data-ajax="false"?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to show loader before the page is opened. If I remove data-ajax="false" is works. But I need to have data-ajax attribute.

```
<a href="..." data-ajax="false" class="show-page-loading-msg">
Home
</a>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? :-) What needs to happen exactly when the user clicks that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.mobile.loading()`

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d39FX/)**

```js
$.mobile.loading("show");
```

And

```
$.mobile.loading("hide");
```